# Post image to Sharepoint List using Http request

Tags: sharepoint, httprequest, power-automate, powerapps

I have the following image in a SharePoint library:

[image]

I wish to Insert this image into an Image Column as part of the metadata of a List called QSAR Analysis Data.

[image]

TEST Flow to try and achieve this I run into all sorts of errors:

Based on: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/08/add-an-image-to-sharepoint-image-columns-using-power-automate/

[image]

Note the title should really say TEST but this is an old screenshot and for testing I don't mind which item the image were to join.

However, I get the following error:

```
The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.QSAR_x0020_Analysis_x0020_DataListItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.
clientRequestId: 87870979-e145-4342-86c3-093dbbf32f26
serviceRequestId: d4e810a1-5019-8000-54bf-d6b1c5f76cb2
```

Removing this I then get another error:

```
The property 'type' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.QSAR_x0020_Analysis_x0020_DataListItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.
clientRequestId: 10825d98-ac88-419a-a5c0-10123d487802
serviceRequestId: 0fe910a1-f029-8000-2b56-b40b4ec74d91
```

Removing this line gives me:

```
{
    "Title": "TEST",
    "Image": {
        "type": "thumbnail",
        "fileName": "TEST.png",
        "fieldName": "Image",
        "serverUrl": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/",
        "serverRelativeUrl": "/sites/xxx/ImageTest/Images/TEST.png"
    }
}
```

But running this I get the following error:

```
An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.
clientRequestId: e6590f4e-1a8a-4256-a6ac-8fc26a3bf1e6
serviceRequestId: 24e910a1-503d-8000-3403-c857782bfc69
```

So I'm clearly just digging myself a hole.

**TO GET IMAGE AVAILABLE IN POWERAPPS**

[image]

Comment: Are you moving image within same SharePoint library

Comment: You are passing value for `ImageColumnName` in `Body` as `object`. Instead, you have to pass the "object" in the form of `String`. Check the value for `Body` parameter in this blog carefully: [Add an image to SharePoint Image columns using Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/08/add-an-image-to-sharepoint-image-columns-using-power-automate/). Let me know if it fixes your last error and works to associate image with list item.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP, Please see Solution below. This was just a proof of concept to see if I could get it to work and it does

Comment: Ok great, glad it worked for you. You should also update the UniqueID of image file to image column value so that it will show the images properly in Power Apps as well (if you connect your list to app). Check value passed to image column at: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/13/add-update-image-columns-in-sharepoint-microsoft-lists-using-pnp-powershell/

Comment: You may be touching on my next question. I will get back to this

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP I do not have acesss to powershell from work computer. But you are right the images are not showing in powerapps. Strangely If I manually copy and paste and image in then it does show. Please could you advise

Comment: Use get file metadata action after your create file action --> You will get UniqueID from the action outputs --> Pass it to `id` property inside the data you passed for image column value. No need to use PowerShell for that, I provided the link just for referring the body given in the article.

Comment: have added to the question: TO GET IMAGE AVAILABLE IN POWERAPPS. 

If you could take a look and please advise. Currently I am getting bad request

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Apologies to Push on this but if you have any further thoughts it would be much appreciated. Been stuck on this for days now. I have successfully mimiced your adding id into the metadata HTTP post request but this causes an error on the server in power apps. Wondering if It can be done with attachments instead. 

Please see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/312521/error-when-trying-to-retrieve-data-from-the-network-following-post-request-to-re if you don't mind!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

[image]

Note I used Branch List which is trying to exactly mimic a video.

If you get a metadata issue, it is because you need the additional headers and need to specify the item you wish to modify using ID.